# Extraer los resultados sueltos de una regresión logistica con Scikit-Learn y llevarlos a un pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, scikit-learn

Estoy trabajando con la librería Scikit-Learn para obtener una regresión logística y **no logro el cómo obtener el Recall, Precision y F1 de cada clase de forma individual**. Únicamente logro obtener la matriz de confusión con sus resultados, pero **requiero obtenerlos de forma individual**, ya que necesito crear una tabla con estos datos y de otras varias regresiones logísticas que estoy realizando para así poder estudiar los resultados de cada una.

El código que uso para la Regresión Logística es...

```
def run_model(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
 clf_base = LogisticRegression(C=1.0, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver="newton-cg")
 clf_base.fit(X_train, y_train)
 return clf_base
```

A continuación, dejo una captura de pantalla con el resultado que obtengo y que me sirve, pero debo copiar a manos los datos que están encerrados en el cuadro rojo y que necesito llevar a una tabla que armo con pandas.

[image: Captura de pantalla de ejemplo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la forma más sencilla y aleccionadora de hacerlo es sabiendo las formulas de **Precision**, **recall** y **f1-score**, son formulas sencillas (simples fracciones) que se pueden realizar con la **matriz de confusión** que has obtenido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde:

- `tp`: Verdaderos Positivos (True Positives), cantidad de datos que para una clase elegida que nuestro modelo ha acertado. Aquí son 408 para la clase cero y 246 para la clase uno.
- `fp`: Falsos positivos (False Positives), cantidad de datos que para una clase elegida que nuestro modelo los ha marcado como uno, pero en realidad son ceros. Si la clase elegida es cero, serán 31. En el caso de que sea uno, serán 71
- `fn`: Falsos Negativos (Flase Negatives), cantidad de datos que nuestro modelo para una clase elegida **ha marcado con un cero pero en realidad son unos**, Aquí son 71 para la clase cero y 31 para la clase 1.
- `Beta`: Es un número cualquiera, por lo general se usa el dos.

### Programamos

Una vez tenemos clara la teoría y las formulas tan solo tenemos que programarlo:

#### 1. Definimos las funciones

```
def precision(tp, fp):
    return tp / (tp + fp)

def recall(tp, fn):
    return tp / (tp + fn)

def f1(precision, recall, beta=2):
    return (beta * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
```

#### 2. Definimos una función que agrupa al resto

```
def metricas(matriz_confusion, categoria, tipo, decimales=2):
    if tipo == "precision": #Precisión
        if categoria == 0:
            return round(precision(matriz_confusion[0][0], matriz_confusion[1][0]), decimales)
        elif categoria == 1:
            return round(precision(matriz_confusion[1][1], matriz_confusion[0][1]), decimales)

    elif tipo == "recall": #Recall
        if categoria == 0:
            return round(recall(matriz_confusion[0][0], matriz_confusion[0][1]), decimales)
        elif categoria == 1:
            return round(recall(matriz_confusion[1][1], matriz_confusion[1][0]), decimales)
            
    elif tipo == "f1":#F1 score
        if categoria == 0:
            prec_f1 = precision(matriz_confusion[0][0], matriz_confusion[1][0])
            recall_f1 = recall(matriz_confusion[0][0], matriz_confusion[0][1])
            return round(f1(prec_f1, recall_f1), decimales)
        elif categoria == 1:
            prec_f1 = precision(matriz_confusion[1][1], matriz_confusion[0][1])
            recall_f1 = recall(matriz_confusion[1][1], matriz_confusion[1][0])
            return round(f1(prec_f1, recall_f1), decimales)

    #Si llegamos aquí lanzamos un error, porque hemos puesto mal el tipo y las categorías
    return ValueError("La categoría o el tipo son incorrectos")
```

#### 3. Utilizamos la matriz de confusión y extraemos los datos

```
#Definimos la matriz de confusión que tienes
prueba =[[408, 71],
        [31, 246]]

print("Precision clase 0: ", metricas(prueba, 0, "precision"))
print("Precision clase 1: ", metricas(prueba, 1, "recall"))
print("Recall clase 0: ",metricas(prueba, 0, "recall"))
print("Recall clase 1: ",metricas(prueba, 1, "recall"))
print("f1 clase 0: ",metricas(prueba, 0, "f1"))
print("f1 clase 1: ",metricas(prueba, 1, "f1"))
```

**Salida:**

```
Precision clase 0:  0.93
Precision clase 1:  0.78
Recall clase 0:  0.85
Recall clase 1:  0.89
f1 clase 0:  0.89
f1 clase 1:  0.83
```

### Bonus

- Puedes mejorar estas funciones documentandolas, creando errores y quedandolo más limpio, eso lo dejo para ti.
- Si quieres saber más sobre estás métricas y más variantes, puedes ver la [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) que tiene una excelente explicación.
- Las formulas de *Precision*, *Recall* y *F1-Score* que he implementado, existen en [Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classification-metrics) por lo que puedes importarlas y el resultado es el mismo.